# can we add two search form in single site?

Tags: 7, search

I have a one search form which is used for all content type but i want another search form which is only for specific content type and show on specific page only. I have install the custom search module but there is no way to show that custom search module in structure block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module so it only searches in your specific content type.

1) Enable custom search and custom search blocks

[image]

2) Now go to `admin/structure/block` and configure `Custom Search 1`

3) Scroll down a bit and click on the blue `CONTENT` text

Then at the bottom, in `Content exclusion`, check mark the content types that you **do not** want to show.

[image]

4) In region settings, select the region you want this block to show up in.

[image]

Comment: i did that configuration but this module is not show on block section to set the view position

Comment: @SumitAggarwal you need to select a region in region settings (scroll all the way down to the bottom)